# Lottie-hosted JSON files: the server responded with a status of 403 ()

Tags: json, http-status-code-403, lottie

I am using Lottie-hosted JSON files in my static website, which was working fine on the locale live server, when I host to my domain it stops working
eg json URL - https://lottie.host/0de28702-1a29-48d3-892d-16f278889351/i4201FkTJi.json

```
browser console error of my website console error
```

when I visit Lottie JSON URL I get this error

```
This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.
<Error>
<Code>AccessDenied</Code>
<Message>Access Denied</Message>
<RequestId>9BFPV8H12FFKQA5H</RequestId>
<HostId>UN5mgMLpV/q4NozUoW/P3WLZKzWmD37x01alsEZysIe1mmkdGe2fShtLlglu5GtJ6uLEnK15jwFF8w1fjDoGtTEv872AiXNCiJ10BkVbn1I=</HostId>
</Error>
```

error screenshots
[image]

Thanks in advance for help